# creating new react native app Received malformed response from registry

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I try to create new react native app but after running `create-react-native-app` I get these errors:

```
create-react-native-app tuts2
 Creating a new React Native app in /mnt/f/try/react-native/tuts2.

Using package manager as yarnpkg with yarn interface.
Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-native-scripts...

yarn add v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-native-scripts > xdl > auth0-js > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0:
error Received malformed response from registry for "timed-out". The 
registry may be down.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this 
command.
Error: Received malformed response from registry for "timed-out". The 
registry may be down.
at /mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:48907:15
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:92:30)
at /mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:110:14
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new F (/mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:29389:28)
at /mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:89:12
at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (/mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:48946:7)
at /mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/lib/cli.js:48963:28
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
yarnpkg add --dev --exact --ignore-optional react-native-scripts failed
```

node version `v8.9.3` and npm version is `5.5.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all of the owner's packages are missing: https://github.com/floatdrop/timed-out/issues/13

Update: NPM bug: https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255